# AuthorizedKeysCommand not getting executed

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, authorization

I'm trying to authorize SSH sessions using the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` in `sshd_config`. For some reason, the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` is not getting executed even though the SSH flow at least initiates the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` flow.

Here's my `AuthorizedKeysCommand` configuration from my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` :

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/local/src/authorized_keys_command.sh
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
```

I changed the `LogLevel` to `DEBUG` and observed the following in the logs :

```
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 65534/65534 (e=0/0)
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 65534/65534 (e=0/0)
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
```

That means the SSH daemon switches to the user `nobody`, but does nothing after that.

I have the following lines in my `authorized_keys_command.sh` script :

```
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "Invoked AuthorizedKeysCommand"

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "No User Specified"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Username : $1"
```

I even tried to debug the issue by passing `/bin/echo` and `/bin/date` to the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` to no avail.

My configuration is as follows :
Operating System : `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS` (with all the latest patches and updates from the apt (ubuntu) repositories applied)
OpenSSH Server : `OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: It gets invoked, but since it does not output any authorized keys, the junk is probably ignored.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` outputs only AuthorizedKeys and nothing else @Jakuje? Shouldn't it be `echo`ing those lines from the script? Or at least `/bin/date`?

Comment: Why it would echo these lines for you? It matches these lines against the offered public key (if you simplify that).

Comment: So does it need a single line command in the script to check for the authorized keys? Can't it run the whole script and then take the output?

Comment: `I changed the LogLevel to DEBUG and observed the following in the logs`

What is the log file that is mentioned here, I believe my command is not working too but not sure where to check the logs for it

Comment: Back in 2017, on a Debian-based machine, it was in `/var/log/auth.log`. But these days with the prevalence of `systemd`, you can use `systemd-journal` to view SSH logs : `journalctl --unit sshd.service` ( assuming that you are running `openssh-server` )

Answer (score 2):

Manual page for `sshd_config` states quite clearly what is expected from the command to do and output:

> `AuthorizedKeysCommand`
>
> Specifies a program to be used to look up the user's public keys.  The program must be owned by root, not writable by group or others and specified by an absolute path.
>
> Arguments to AuthorizedKeysCommand may be provided using the following tokens, which will be expanded at runtime: %% is replaced by a literal '%', %u is replaced by the username being authenticated, %h is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated, %t is replaced with the key type offered for authentication, %f is replaced with the fingerprint of the key, and %k is replaced with the key being offered for authentication.  If no arguments are specified then the username of the target user will be supplied.
>
> **The program should produce on standard output zero or more lines of `authorized_keys` output** (see **AUTHORIZED_KEYS** in `sshd(8)`).  If a key supplied by AuthorizedKeysCommand does not successfully authenticate and authorize the user then public key authentication continues using the usual AuthorizedKeysFile files.  By default, no AuthorizedKeysCommand is run.

So yes, the `date` and `echo` you tried to write in your command are most probably ignored as junk/invalid output. If you want this to authorize your user, you need a script to produce public key in the expected format (see manual page for `sshd` for more info).

Comment: Is there a timeout interval that the `sshd` waits before switching over to the next method / public key? Can this interval be modified?

My script needs to make an external API call that would take approximately 5-10 seconds to return an `AuthorizedKey`, but I'm guessing  `sshd` skips in 2-3 seconds which in turn fails my authentication mechanism.

Comment: No. It just [waits for the command to exit](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/auth2-pubkey.c#L525)

Comment: I finally figured it out, it was because of incorrect configuration of the `AuthorizedKeysCommandUser`. I was trying to run the script as a user which didn't have the right configurations to call the external API that I was using. It was an oversight on my end. My bad.